# Blocks vs One page application

Tags: angular, laravel, reactjs, vuejs2

I'm building a Laravel project, and in my case there are some blocks on my app (users logged in, constant fetching on stream data from API regarding a sports information,...) and I these specific blocks instead of using jQuery I wish to use js frameworks like angular for example, but I feel that most of the examples that I see online is focusing in making the app in the frontend level one page application instead of some blocks on my page.

Is it wrong trying to animate only some blocks on my page? Is this a problem? And which js framework is better to do this, since I feel in the angular framework I feel there are more dependencies comparing with the angularjs 1.5.

Any suggestion?

Comment: all js frameworks do the same things, also what is `block` in the context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue.js framework initially not build for the single page apps. As you said you can you Vue.js for parts of your application. There is nothing wrong to use like so.